# Run node.js code on startup

Tags: raspbian, boot

I've been trying to run this code on startup for the last two days:

[image: Screenshot of code]

I've tried the `rc.local` method, the `init.d` method and `sudo crontab -e` method but none of them worked for me !

The file is executable (`sudo chmod +x InitiateSensors.js`)

I am accessing the Raspberry Pi remotely using `xrdp` and user pi.

Any ideas why this isn't working ?

Comment: Does it work when you start your script manually from a terminal window? And your script seems to rely on the Desktop being active. Have you tried to add it to the LXDE autostart file (/home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart)?

Comment: thanks for your answer :D
yes manually it's working fine, and no i don't know how to use the LXDE

Comment: should use /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart since it needs access to the desktop.. working good, thanks you!

Comment: Please post your code as text and not a screenshot, as that makes it searchable and *way* easier to read.

Comment: @Greenonline the only problem is that I am accessing the pi remotely and didn't find any way to copy paste through xrdp!

Comment: Ah, ok, fair enough, I guess :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script seems to rely on the Desktop being active. The best method is probably to add it to the GUI autostart file. For Raspbian that's /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Add a line Like

```
@InitiateSensors.js
```

or

```
@lxterminal -e InitiateSensors.js
```

You may have to use the full path to the script